# Best approach to add keyboard "Shortcuts/Hotkeys" to control my application

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I'm working on a desktop application in which I want to allow the user to control it's functionalities via Keyboard, also allow him to change the default controllers to a custom controllers according to his point of view.

My question is, what is the best approach to tackle this problem and provide an appropriate solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you want to handle any other custom controllers ? Because I guess that you can't just do a generic code for everything

Comment: What I want for example: if the default controller that I assigned for a certain functionality in my app  is button "A", and the user want to change it to be button "B"

Like what happening in Games for example.

Comment: Ho, so it's more like changing key shortcuts than changing controllers, didn't anderstand this this way. I may have an idea (using Dictionnary) about how doing it, I'll try it and if works well post an answer.

Comment: yes changing the key shortcuts, and I'm waiting for your idea thanks, 

so again to be clear for you, the problem could be as follows: 

1- Assigning certain functionalities in the application to be controlled from the keyboard "like computer games".
2- Give the user the ability to change the shortcuts if he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use a *Dictionary* to bound each key to an action

My approach here is to use a *Dictionary* where the Key is actual Keybord *Keys* and value is an *int?* representing one of your function that can be bound to a custom input.

```
Dictionnary<Keys, int?> shortcutDictionnary = new Dictionary<Keys, int?>();
// Add a new Keys
shortcutDictionary.Add(Keys.A, 1);
// Change a Keys value (change shortcut bounded to it)
shortcutDictionary[Keys.A] = 4;
```

To match those *int?* with these functions you only have to use a *switch* :

```
int? num = null;
if (this.shortcutDictionary.TryGetValue(keyPressed, out num))
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1:
            attack();
            break;
        case 2:
            defend();
            break;
        case 3:
            hide();
            break;
        case 4:
            dance();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Key not bounded");
            break;
    }
}
```

I also in my code below use an *enum* instead of direct use of *Keys* for my *Dictionary*. 
This way, I can choose which *Keys* can be bounded and which one can't.

My code made from a Winform app, as an exemple I only used 4 *Keys* (A,B,C,D) which can be bound and one to easily change bound (L), but I'm sure you can figure out how to change bound easily with any other method. Also as I'm working with a WindowsForm, I had to set *KeyPreview* = true.

Here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public enum UsableKeys
    {
        A = Keys.A,
        B = Keys.B,
        C = Keys.C,
        D = Keys.D,
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<UsableKeys, int?> shortcutDictionary = new Dictionary<UsableKeys, int?>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (UsableKeys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(UsableKeys)))
            {
                // You may add default shortcut here
                this.shortcutDictionary.Add(key, null);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            UsableKeys keyPressed = (UsableKeys)e.KeyCode;
            if (this.shortcutDictionary.ContainsKey(keyPressed))
            {
                executeAction(keyPressed);

                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.L)
            {
                switch (this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.A])
                {
                    case 1:
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.A] = 4;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.B] = 3;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.C] = 2;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.D] = 1;
                        break;
                    case null:
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.A] = 1;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.B] = 2;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.C] = 3;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.D] = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.A] = null;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.B] = null;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.C] = null;
                        this.shortcutDictionary[UsableKeys.D] = null;
                        break;
                }

                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        private void executeAction(UsableKeys keyPressed)
        {
            int? num = null;
            if (this.shortcutDictionary.TryGetValue(keyPressed, out num))
            {
                switch (num)
                {
                    case 1:
                        attack();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        defend();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        hide();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        dance();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Key not bounded");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void attack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player swing his word");
        }

        private void defend()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player raise his shield");
        }

        private void hide()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player sneak around");
        }

        private void dance()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player start to dance");
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, output will be like :

```
// Press A, B, C or D
"Key not bounded"
// Press L
// Press A
"Player swing his word"
// Press B
"Player raise his shield"
// Press C
"Player sneak around"
// Press D
"Player start to dance"
// Press L
// Press A
"Player start to dance"
// Press B
"Player sneak around"
// Press C
"Player raise his shield"
// Press D
"Player swing his sword"
// Press L
// Press A, B, C or D
"Key not bounded"
```

Exemple to change key binding in run time :

```
// Create a new Dictionary for shortcuts
Dictionary<UsableKeys, int?> shortcutDictionary = new Dictionary<UsableKeys, int?>();
// Add a pair key/value that bind A to attack()
shortcutDictionary.Add(UsableKey.A, 1);
// Add a pair Key/value that bind B to defend()
shortcutDictionary.Add(UsableKey.B, 2);
// Now, if you press A, attack() will be called
shortcutDictionary[UsableKey.A] = 2;
// Now if you press A or B, defend() will be called
shortcutDictionary[UsableKey.B] = null;
// Now B isn't bind to any function, so only A is binded to defend();
```

With this method, you can't bind multiple functions to one *Keys* while you can bind multiple *Keys* to one function (If you want to inverse that, just swap key/value of *Dictionary* and adjust the code to match this).

I don't know if it's the optimal way to do this, but it isn't spaghetti code and it works well.

Comment: okay, now there is still two issues we can discuss; the first one is how we can allow user to modify the controllers in run time and how to save the user modification, I can recommend that saving the modification can be via XML file

Comment: @AhmadShaarawi to save it you may create a file with informations into it, or try to embed a database and save it there (with this aproach the dictionary isn't relevant anymore elsewhere than option menu before saving changes, you just have to update database). To change shortcut in run time (assuming you're not using database) you just have to change the value of the dictionary. I'm going to add a more detailed exemple for that in my answer.

Comment: ops, I think I was not clear, I mean to let the application user to change the controller he dealing with while he is using the application

Comment: I want to thank you for your idea, it helped me to build up my approach based on it but with some modifications

Comment: @AhmadShaarawi Didn't see your comment yesterday, but to change the shortcut you just have to build a function where the client side send a key and an int and change it like in my example ^^ I didn't anderstand that you wanted me to show you exactly how you should do it (in a console program for example, the simplest way to show it). But I'm glad if my answer helped you find a solution.